# DirectX 11.2 development on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, directx, windows-8.1, directx-11

The dynamic HLSL shader linking feature is (perhaps intentionally) only available in DirectX 11.2 on Windows 8.1+ and I found this out a little late in the game. I'm not able to upgrade my dev box at this time but in the near future I may have access to a separate machine that does have Win8.1.

Is there a way I can compile (but not run) my project with DirectX 11.2 on my Windows 7 machine so I can get access to this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the only 11.2 feature you use you can actually both build and run it on Windows 7, since you are allowed to redistribute `d3dcompiler_47.dll` (which implements the linking entrypoints) with your application.  Just install the 8.1 SDK on your Win7 machine, and you should end up with all the necessary files to build and run: `d3dcompiler.lib`, `d3dcompiler.h`, and `d3dcompiler_47.dll`.  Note you can find the redistributable version of the dll under `Windows Kits\8.1\Redist\D3D`.

If you don't want to install the full SDK on your dev machine, you can install it somewhere else and just manually copy over the header and lib.  In general it's a bad idea to mix and match SDK components but the HLSL compiler shouldn't have any cross-dependencies that would cause problems.